# already logged page should be display when open new tab in struts2

Tags: struts2

I developing  Struts2 project.
In that project the user can log in and do something its work fine.
If that user open the new tab and type my project url it will show the same page(after login page).
How do I implement the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be doing like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557733/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-having-multiple-instances-of-the-same-web-application), in a question almost identical to your (concept is the same, only the implementation, on .NET, differs).

> Calculate an unique value each time you pass in the Action, then put
>   it in a session variable  (that is server side) and use it to feed an
>   hidden field on the web page (that is client side).
>
> When the page will post back (submit) the form containing your hidden field, you
>   will see if the page field and the session field are the same.
>
> If yes: it is (the only OR) the last page / tab opened.
>
> If no: you are trying to submit the form from a page that is not the
>   last page opened.

This way, you will always have only one instance of the web application, and if you open another instance of the web application in a new page / tab, it will invalidate the previous one: only the last opened will be valid (because of multiple hidden fields, one for each page, but only one session variable).

IF you really need (do you?) to prevent the user opening a new tab instead of ensuring a single instance for the web-app, start working from this principle and eventually come back here (better with some code)